# Question about Legendre Symbol and Division Q12(a)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

Let $q>3$ be an odd prime and let $q=2Q+1$. Prove that:

(a) $q\,|\,(3^Q-1) \iff q\equiv ±1 \pmod {12}$

adpated from Number Theory with Applications, James A. Anderson, James M. Bell. Ch 3.9 Q12 (a)

Any hint from the question? Thanks.

Edit 1: (DELETED BECAUSE IT IS WRONG)
Edit 2: I have proved for the one-sided statement. Let me put it here first and wait for me to prove the another side of statement

Lemma 1: Iff $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}^+, x>3:  x^2\equiv 3 \pmod {p}$, then $p\equiv\pm1 \pmod{12}$

Proof:

Forward Statement:

By quadratic reciprocity, $(\frac{p}{3})=(\frac{3}{p})(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} \frac{3-1}{2}}=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

For $y^2\equiv p \pmod{3}$,

Case 1: If $(\frac{p}{3})=0$, then $3 \mid p \Rightarrow p \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

Case 2: If $(\frac{p}{3})=1$, then by Fermat little thm, $y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, $\therefore p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$

On the other hand, $1=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \Rightarrow p$ is even.

$\therefore$ By Chinese Remainder theorem, $p \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$

Case 3: If $(\frac{p}{3})=-1$, then $y^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, $\therefore p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$

On the other hand, $-1=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

$\therefore \exists t \in \mathbb{Z}^+: \frac{p-1}{2} = 2t+1 \Rightarrow p-1=4t+2\Rightarrow p=4t+3\Rightarrow p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

By Chinese Remainder theorem, $p \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$

Combining the latter two cases, $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{12}$

Edit 3: Here is the proof of backward statement:

If $p$ is an odd prime, then $(\frac{p}{3}) \equiv p \pmod{3}$

Case 1: $p\equiv 1 \pmod{12} \Rightarrow p\equiv 1 \pmod{3}, \therefore (\frac{p}{3})=1$

Also, $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^+: p-11=12 \alpha \Rightarrow p=12\alpha +11$

$(\frac{3}{p})=(\frac{p}{3}) (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=1(-1)^{\frac{12t}{2}}=1$

Case 2: $p\equiv 11 \pmod{12} \Rightarrow p\equiv -1 \pmod{3}, \therefore (\frac{p}{3})=-1$

$\therefore \exists \beta \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : p-11=12 \beta \Rightarrow p=12\beta +11$

$(\frac{3}{p})=(\frac{p}{3})(-1)^{\frac{12\beta+11-1}{2}}=(-1)(-1)=1$

Combining the above two cases, $(\frac{p}{3}) = 1$

Edit 4:

There are two cases: $q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $q\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$:

Case 1: $q \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow (\frac{q}{3}) = (\frac{3}{q})(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}} = 1, \therefore q\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$

$\therefore$ By Chinese Remainder thm, $q \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$

Case 2: $q \equiv 3 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow (\frac{q}{3}) = -1, \therefore q \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$

$\therefore$ By Chinese Remainder thm, $q \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$

(The converse way is similar to that in edit 3).

(Edit 5: I changed the above from "statement" to "lemma 1")

Edit 5:

By using Lemma 1,

$(\frac{3}{q}) = 1 \Leftrightarrow (\frac{3}{q})  \equiv 3^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod{q} \Leftrightarrow 1 \equiv 3^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \pmod{q}$

$\therefore$ The thm is proved.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Can you use the given  data to determine whether or not $3$ is a square $\pmod q$ for instance?

Comment: @lulu Here is the proof that 3 is not the square (mod q): https://imgur.com/a/EqxNQBd

Comment: But $3$ is a square $\pmod q$.  For instance, take $q=11$, so $Q=5$.  Then $11$ divides $3^5-1=242$, and $3\equiv 5^2\pmod {11}$.

Comment: @lulu I used Euler Criterion to find that when q≡±1 (mod 12), x^2≡3 (mod q) (Edit: https://imgur.com/gwYDgoj)

Comment: Edit your question if you want to add information...don't add links.  Links don't last, and the site is meant to be a repository for questions.   That said, you are certainly correct that, at least for $p>3$, $3$ is a square $\pmod p$ iff $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod {12}$.

Comment: Should add,  quadratic reciprocity is the best tool for this sort of thing.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry about that, because I have not learnt $\LaTeX{}$ yet, so writing the code would be a relatively time-consuming job for me. Anyways, I would learn $\LaTeX{}$ code as early as I can, since I know that this skill is crucial.

BTW, I have finished the proof of statement by editing. Have a look, thanks.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work.  we have  $\left( \frac 3q\right)=1$ so split into cases according to $q\pmod 4$.  It takes two lines.

Comment: @lulu I have done the alternative proof. It is really simpler than the former approach.

Comment: @lulu I think that I have used your given lemma to prove the entire theorem. Have a look, thanks.

Comment: I think the argument you call "Edit $4$" looks good.